# Memory usage with loading file into PHP

Tags: php, file-io, memory-limit

I am loading a file into an array in PHP. I am loading the file into an array because it is a dictionary and I'd like to utilize a binary search to find whether my word is in the dictionary or not. I have tried this two different ways due to some various pieces of information out there. They have very similar times and for some reason my 1.1MB file is causing PHP to utilize 20MB of memory.

Method 1:

```
<?php
    echo 'Memory Usage Start: ' . memory_get_usage() . '<br>';
    $start = microtime(true);
    $fs=fopen("./dictionary.txt", "r");
    $dictionary=array();
    while (!feof($fs)){
        $dictionary[]=trim(fgets($fs));
    }
    $end = microtime(true);
    echo 'Memory Usage End: ' . memory_get_usage() . '<br>';
    echo 'Total Time: ' . ($end - $start) . ' seconds';
```

Output is:

```
Memory Usage Start: 5298144
Memory Usage End: 25254944
Total Time: 0.17744994163513 seconds
```

Method 2:

```
<?php
    echo 'Memory Usage Start: ' . memory_get_usage() . '<br>';
    $start = microtime(true);
    $dictionary = file('./dictionary.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $end = microtime(true);
    echo 'Memory Usage End: ' . memory_get_usage() . '<br>';
    echo 'Total Time: ' . ($end - $start) . ' seconds';
```

Output is:

```
Memory Usage Start: 5297240
Memory Usage End: 25244920
Total Time: 0.074188947677612 seconds
```

It seems there is a much larger overhead with arrays in PHP than I had imagined. I guess one solution I can think of is to parse to the middle of the file and just read that line, and do the binary search that way. However it seems much more inefficient to do so many file reads to find a value.

Anyways any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Each array node is a string zval in its own right, with the additional overhead of a zval. Try loading your dictionary into a database (even simply SQLite if that's all you have); you'll not have the memory overheads, and a database can be indexed making searching easier

Comment: I'd prefer not to as it will be in a plugin for a piece of software and I want to avoid creating DB tables if at all possible.

Comment: +1 to @MarkBaker. Use a table, adapt it to the main program database. Many plugins choose this way. On installation and runtime they check the framework etc and use framework database and a private table. The pros are too much that you will regret if you keep away from that checking and adapting routine which is the only 'seemingly' con of this approach.

Comment: use `file_get_contents` it returns the file into string

Comment: @Amir, reduces memory usage, but how would you suggest doing the search efficiently? strops() on the string?

Comment: Method2 should be faster because method1 reads all rows. In method2 I guess (yes, I really don't know by facts) the options FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES and FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES makes the process faster (because it doesn't have to add every single line into an array). And of course file() is core a php-function...

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, `strpos()`  is an option